# How to include dll as relative path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, dllimport

I have a dll in my project which I am referring through absolute path(C:\test\something\abc.dll) to load in my project. How do load it relatively or is there is better way to include it in visual studio project?

Comment: You say "in my project", but where does that absolute path actually occur? It could be a project file, or an #import statement, or a LoadLibrary argument, or something else. The answers could be different in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify dll name without path and place the dll in the same directory where the executable loading it resides, or in the current directory (the one from which you launch the program).

Comment: ya i tried that. Its working. Is that a best way to do it or is there some standard way of doing if i want publish my application elsewhere

Comment: I think placing dll in the executable directory and loading it by name without path  is pretty  standard.

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)::

> Before the system searches for a DLL, it checks the following:
>
> - If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system
>   uses the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system
>   does not search for the DLL.
> - If the DLL is on the list of known DLLs
>   for the version of Windows on which the application is running, the
>   system uses its copy of the known DLL (and the known DLL's dependent
>   DLLs, if any). The system does not search for the DLL. For a list of
>   known DLLs on the current system, see the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\KnownDLLs.

The standard searching order for Dlls is::

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The system directory.
> 4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 5. The Windows directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the **PATH** environment variable.

You can always have your Dll with the application in the same directory. Carrying it as resource within application is not advisable.

Comment: Thanks abhineet for your help