# How to add/link *.dll from QT5 into Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, qt5

Although I set "AdditionalDependencies", "AdditionalLibraryDirectories", "LocalDebuggerEnvironment" in *.vcxproj, *.vcxproj.user, Visual studio still looks for  Q5*.dll files in the current output directory $(OutDir)

I tried to search how to add/link dll files,and I found that dll files should be copied to the output directory. It works of course.

Is there anyway to set the path of dll files in Visual Studio 2017?
It looks like  "AdditionalDependencies", "AdditionalLibraryDirectories", "LocalDebuggerEnvironment" don't work in my case.

The below is the  section in the *.vcxproj

```
<AdditionalDependencies> Qt5Charts.lib;Qt5Widgets.lib;Qt5Gui.lib;Qt5Core.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
<AdditionalLibraryDirectories> $(QTDIR)\lib;C:\QT\5.12.0\MSVC2017_64\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
<AdditionalOptions>"/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
```

and in *.vcxproj.user

```
<LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin%3bC:\QT\5.12.0\MSVC2017_64\bin%3b$(PATH)</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>   <
```

As a result,my application can be launched and the message is about "missing DLL".

I just checked module dependency of my application by the utility "Dependencies"

It seems like the paths of dll files(Qt5Charts.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll, Qt5Gui.dll,Qt5Core.dll) are not resolved, so there are no information on these modules and question marks are shown for these modules in the window of "Dependencies".

When I make copies into the directory $(OutDir), the paths of these modules are resolved correctly as $(OutDir)

Any suggestions/clues/answers will be VERY appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for typo: As a result,my application can NOT be launched and the message is about "missing DLL".

Comment: At least, my application works after I include the path of dlls into the windows enthronement variable "PATH".  this is because of the dll file search order.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685962/how-to-include-dll-as-relative-path